# Raspberry Pi SSH access over internet and public server WWW

Tags: server, raspberry-pi, public

I want to get access to my RPi over internet and I want to get access to my apache server and www site. Till now I used "weaved" servicess but after disconnected I  always have to login on weaved.com and get ip address. My RPi is connected to my laptop, and laptop is connected via WIFI to router (I don't have access to router).
I set static IP on RPi. I have internet in RPi. So how can I build public server with access www site on my RPi and also want to connect over internet wity RPi via SSH. Help me, I've read a lot of web sites about this. But still I dont know what to do and what I need (DNS, VPN, VNC, forwarding ports, openVPN, no-ip)...

Answer (score 0):

You'll need [Dynamic DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) service (unless you have a fixed IP) and you'll want to forward port 80/443 from your router to your local IP of your RPi.

The [first result on Google](http://raspberrywebserver.com/serveradmin/get-your-raspberry-pi-web-site-on-line.html) provides a good guide.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done by using a tunnelling service, so you can get access to both the web server running on your Raspberry Pi, as well as accessing the SSH terminal remotely over the internet.

Checkout these articles that might help:
https://www.pitunnel.com/doc/access-ssh-session-remote-terminal-raspberry-pi-over-internet
https://www.pitunnel.com/doc/access-http-website-raspberry-pi-over-internet
https://www.pitunnel.com/doc/access-vnc-remote-desktop-raspberry-pi-over-internet